# Ruby - collect same numbers from array into array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, refactoring

I have created a very ugly script to collect same numbers from an array. I don't think this is a very Ruby way :) Anyone could provide a more clean solution?

```
ar = [5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6]

collections = []
collect_same = []

while ar.length > 0
 first = ar.values_at(0).join.to_i 
 second = ar.values_at(1).join.to_i 
  if ar.length == 1 
   collect_same << ar[0]
   collections << collect_same
   break
  else  
   sum = ar.values_at(0, 1).inject {|a,b| a + b}
   if second == first 
    p collect_same << ar[0]
    ar.shift 
   else 
    collect_same << ar[0]
    collections << collect_same
    collect_same = []
    ar.shift 
   end 
  end 
end 

p collections
```

The output:

```
=> [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Note, that in primary array same numbers always goes one after another. 
So I wouldn't have primary array like this - `ar = [1, 2, 1, 2]`

Comment: You said it doesn't happen, but _if_ you'd use `[1, 2, 1, 1]` as the input, would you expect `[[1, 1, 1], [2]]` or `[[1], [2], [1, 1]]` as the output?

Comment: @Stefan, I guess the output would be `[[1], [2], [1, 1]]` but this is not what I would expect to **have** in my code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
[5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6].chunk_while(&:==).to_a
#=> [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Ruby prior to 2.3:

```
[5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6].each_with_object([]) do |e, acc|
  acc.last && acc.last.last == e ? acc.last << e : acc << [e]
end
#=> [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 5):

In case if you want to do it without order:

```
ar.group_by(&:itself).values
 => [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: The result doesn't look unordered, what does "without order" mean?

Comment: @Stefan, I mean `[1, 2, 1]`  case would return `[[1, 1], [2]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
[5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6].slice_when(&:!=).to_a
  #=> [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

One could perhaps say that [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) and [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) are [ying and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang).

Prior to Ruby v2.3, one might write

```
[5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6].chunk(&:itself).map(&:last)
```

and prior to v2.2,

```
[5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6].chunk { |n| n }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: One could perhaps even examine the source code of [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) and see that ... (drumroll) ... `slice_when` is the origin!

Answer (score 0):

just another oneliner

```
arr = [5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6] 
arr.uniq.map {|e| [e]*arr.count(e) }
# => [[5, 5], [2, 2, 2], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: Computing `count` for each unique element is relatively inefficient. Better, for example, would be to first get all the counts in one pass: `counts = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }`, Then `arr.uniq.map {|e| [e]*counts[e] }`.